# Creating directories with symbolic links on apache 2.4

Tags: linux, apache, command-line, command, symlink

I'm having a problem with my configuration on `apache` 2.4.

In the directory configured in `apache` I have symbolic links to the public directories of my web apps. This way:
`/var/www/html/App` -> `/home/user/workspace/App/Public/` (-> symbolic link to).

When I try to create a directory not in the public part of the app (../ for example), it creates it on `/var/www/html/` instead of `/home/user/workspace/App/`.

Using `apache` 2.2 it works as I want, creating it on `/home/user/workspace/App/`, but with the same configuration it doesn't work on `apache` 2.4

This is my configuration of virtual host for apache:

`<Directory /var/www/html/>
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>`

I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Thanks!

Comment: What "it" is creating directories?

Comment: Twig is creating directories. We have a folder with cached views at the private part of the app.